How to Work with CLR Assemblies in AWS RDS SQL Server 2019 with CLR Strict Security Enabled
I'm facing challenges executing a CLR assembly in AWS RDS SQL Server 2019. Due to the enforced CLR strict security, I'm unable to mark the assembly as trusted using sp_add_trusted_assembly as it requires sysadmin privileges. Also, I am not able to create certificate nor asymmetric key in order to create a assembly from it. So, overall I don't have privileges to work more in AWS RDS.
Error:
CREATE or ALTER ASSEMBLY for assembly 'CLRAssemblyTestProject' with the SAFE or EXTERNAL_ACCESS option failed because the 'clr strict security' option of sp_configure is set to 1. Microsoft recommends that you sign the assembly with a certificate or asymmetric key that has a corresponding login with UNSAFE ASSEMBLY permission. Alternatively, you can trust the assembly using sp_add_trusted_assembly. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 10343)
https://sqlquantumleap.com/2017/08/16/sqlclr-vs-sql-server-2017-part-3-clr-strict-security-solution-2/
I tried the above article but I am stuck at creating certificate due to permission privilege which cannot be done in AWS RDS.

I have a feeling that you can't run CLR in AWS unless you manage the server yourself or use older sql server, read this article as well: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/migrate-your-sql-server-workload-with-clr-integration-to-aws/

@siggemannen I had already gone through this article and also tried the steps for AWS RDS but it didn't helped out. I don't want to change the sql server to any other custom RDS but just want to upgrade the version in order to use the inbuilt functions. I also tried changing the 'compatibility level' of particular db but was not able create assembly.

Well, like i wrote, it might not be possible to run :/ What are you doing with the CLR? Perhaps there's another way of doing things

I have a tripleDES encryption which is used in SQL sp's so without CLR it will stop working and I cannot implement same TripleDES in SQL Server directly.

Can't you use ENCRYPT/DECRYPT native functions? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/choose-an-encryption-algorithm?view=sql-server-ver16

No in SQL Server 2019 the support for the TripleDES is deprecated. So, it only has AES algorithm. For now what I see I would need to go with custom RDS only which may help me to get control over db and use SQLCLR.

Can you decrypt stuff and then reencrypt using newer algos? Seems like TripleDES is kinda obsolete in general?

If I use new algos then it will be major change in my project so it will be like recreation of my project with new algo which is not preferred.
